# devtools::document() printing "Writing NAMESPACE" to the console twice

Tags: r, devtools

**tl;dr:** Why is `devtools::document()` printing `Writing NAMESPACE` to the console twice, despite seeming to function normally?

I am following H[ilary Parker's great intro](https://hilaryparker.com/2014/04/29/writing-an-r-package-from-scratch/) to the basics of creating an R package. Her instructions seem to work, but something weird is happening when I run the following code:

```
setwd("C:/Users/JT/R")
dir.create("parent_directory")
library("devtools")
library(roxygen2)
setwd("parent_directory")
create("cats")
file.copy(
    "C:/Users/JT/Desktop/JT Package/cat_function.R", 
    file.path(getwd(), "cats", "R", "cat_function.R")
)
setwd("./cats")
document()
```

After running `documents()` the following prints to the console:

```
Updating cats documentation
Loading cats
Updating roxygen version in C:\Users\JT\R\parent_directory\cats/DESCRIPTION
Writing NAMESPACE
Writing NAMESPACE
Writing cat_function.Rd
```

If I continue the installation and testing with the following code everything seems to work as expected:

```
setwd("..")
library("cats")
cat_function()
?cat_function
```

I would ignore the weirdness of `Writing NAMESPACE` being reported twice if it weren't for the fact that when I try to adapt Hilary's code to my own custom functions I am having a lot of problems.